# Почему появляется полоса прокрутки?

Tags: bootstrap, вёрстка, css

Подключил третий `bootstrap`.

Пишу код:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">blablabla</div>
</div>
```

И появляется горизонтальная прокрутка в браузере. Для класса "`row`" указано `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;` Почему так происходит? Как избавить от прокрутки?

Comment: > Для класса "row" указано margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;

Это компенсанция аналогичных паддингов в `.container`, в который, по задумке, должны оборачиваться все `.row`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас, скорее всего, не из-за этого элемента прокрутка, покажите полностью страницу.
+ этот код желательно в `<div class="container">` помещать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете прочесть здесь http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid

> .row должны быть помещены в .container (fixed-width) или
>   .container-fluid (full-width) для правильного выравнивания и
>   заполнения.

Выглядеть, соответственно, должно так:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня тоже такая проблема была возникла. страница была напичкана различными контейнерами (и container, и container-fluid). В итоге полоса прокрутки появлялась из-за нехватки одного закрывающего тега div

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за конкретный пример кода, решающий проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда бывает, что в отладчике (*Chrome* например) есть горизонтальная прокрутка, а когда проверяешь страницу на реальном устройстве — её нет.
Попробуйте проверить на целевом устройстве, если есть такая возможность.

Answer (score -1):

вместо

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

надо вставить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```